# error en el menú superior de mi web tras actualización de plugins y templates en wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

he actualizado varios templates y plugins de mi web que tengo creada en wordpress y tras actualizarlos, el menú superior de mi web se me ha desconfigurado y no consigo arreglarlo.

Hay alguna forma de volver a las versiones anteriores de esos plugins y templates para ver si así se me soluciona o alguna forma de volver a configurar el menú para que se vea bien.

ahora me aparece de esta forma:

[image: Menú superior desconfigurado]

Muchas gracias

Comment: revisa las notas del patch y trata de hacer compatible el theme, por mientras podes hacer un downgrade buscando el tag en el svn https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/nombre-del-plugin/tags/ el nombre-del-plugin es el que se ve en el repo de wordpress https://wordpress.org/plugins/nombre-del-plugin ( por lo general es igual al nombre de la carpeta en wp-content/plugins ) si actualizaste via `wp-cli` las versiones anteriores quedan en ~/.cache/wp-cli/plugins

Comment: Hola, estoy no es un sitio de soporte, no podemos ayudarte con problemas de plugins si no hay ningun codigo que podemos analizar, por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour]